# how can I have it show me the values of the x axis in y and vice versa

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.load('/home/josep/workspace/data/wind_5.npy')
plt.pcolor(data)
plt.colorbar()
plt.ylabel('Range')
plt.xlabel('time')
#plt.savefig("/home/josep/workspace/schain/plots_data/test.png")
plt.show()
```

wind_5 is a array with size (527, 132)

[it's a range vs time chart 527 times and 132 ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuzQF.png)
I need the 527 time to be on the x axis and the 132 ranges on the y axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to plot the transpose of the data,

```
plt.pcolor(data.T)
```